# .NET bug: ldtoken of an instantiated generic method

Tags: .net, generics, cil

I'm trying to get the `ldtoken` IL method to load a generic instantiation of a generic method within a generic class (say, `List.ConvertAll<TOutput>`):

```
ldtoken method instance
    class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!0> 
    [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1::ConvertAll<string>(
        class [mscorlib]System.Converter`2<!0,!!0>)
```

This results in an exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1' from assembly 'TestAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

It's looking in my test assembly for `System.Collections.Generic.List`, even though it's explicitly declared in `mscorlib`!

However, loading the uninstantiated method token works:

```
ldtoken method instance
    class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!0> 
    [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1::ConvertAll<[1]>(
        class [mscorlib]System.Converter`2<!0,!!0>)
```

A generic method in a non-generic class works:

```
ldtoken method void [mscorlib]System.Array::Sort<object>(!!0[])
ldtoken method void [mscorlib]System.Array::Sort<[1]>(!!0[])
```

What's going on? Is this a bug in .NET? (I've replicated it on the v2 and v4 CLR)

Comment: Should your converter be something like `class [mscorlib]System.Converter\`2<!!0,string>`?

Comment: No, cos apart from the actual generic instantiation, method signatures are specified in the uninstantiated context

Comment: Same error - `TypeLoadException` with the same message

Comment: Don't you need a generic instantiation of the type itself?  That is, I'd expect something like ... System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>::ConvertAll<string>(...).

Comment: @kvb: That isn't valid il syntax

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, I think you need to instantiate the generic type (i.e. there is no such type as `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 `` - just `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1<object> ``, etc.).

By playing around with System.Reflection.Emit, it looks like it's possible to use ldtoken with an instantiated or uninstantiated method on an instantiated generic type:

```
ldtoken method instance 
    class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!0> 
    class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<object>::ConvertAll<[1]>(
        class [mscorlib]System.Converter`2<!0,!!0>)
ldtoken method instance 
    class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!0> 
    class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<object>::ConvertAll<string>(
        class [mscorlib]System.Converter`2<!0,!!0>)
```

but not with an uninstantiated generic type.  Partition II, section 9.4 of the ECMA CLI spec states that

> The CLI does not support partial instantiation of generic types.  And
>   generic types shall not appear uninstantiated anywhere in metadata
>   signature blobs.

so perhaps this isn't surprising - there doesn't seem to be any way to use ldtoken with the equivalent of `typeof(List<>).GetMethod("ConvertAll")`.

Comment: Nope - that isn't valid IL syntax. You can't specify a type instantiation and method instantiation in the same token

Comment: @thecoop - I don't know what to tell you, but that's what ildasm outputs when a (working) assembly generated by Reflection.Emit is dissassembled, and ilasm seems to accept it without issue when reassembling it.  How else would you indicate the instantiated type?

Comment: @thecoop - Though I'm using the .NET 4.5 beta, so perhaps the behavior is different for previous versions of .NET?

Comment: @thecoop - I get the same thing when I compile `Expression<Func<List<object>, Converter<object,string>, List<string>>> f = (l,c) => l.ConvertAll(c);` in C#, targeting .NET 3.5.

Comment: By using the GetMethodFromHandle(RuntimeMethodHandle, RuntimeTypeHandle) overload. I've tried compiling a method in IL consisting only of that instruction, and ilasm fails with a syntax error at the '<' of the type instantiation.

Comment: @thecoop - What do you get from ildasm if you compile the C# code from my previous comment? ilasm works fine for me with either of the ldtokens I wrote in my answer (and a ret) in a method.